# How to display only the date from sql result

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

```
 Dim sel As String = "select * from personal_i where number= @number"
            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sel, conn)
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", Label61.Text)
            Dim dataset As New DataSet
            adapter.Fill(dataset)
 Label1.Text = dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(6).ToString
```

The result is :

> 8/7/2015 12:00:00 AM

**How do I display only the date, not with time?**

Comment: What data type is `Item(6)`? Most [SQL date data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733.aspx) also include the time but you should be able to format it in ASP.NET to display only the date. Also, this is `[vb.net]`, not `[vba]`.

Comment: it's the data , that i get from sql database ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the format function.

```
 Label1.Text = Format(dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(6).ToString, “Short Date”)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like :

```
    Dim sel As String = "select * from personal_i where number= @number"
                Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sel, conn)
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", Label61.Text)
                Dim dataset As New DataSet
                adapter.Fill(dataset)

     Label1.Text = Format(Trim(Split(dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(6).ToString," ")(0)),"m/d/yyyy")
```

Answer (score -1):

Label1.Text = dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(6).ToString(dd/MM/yyy)

I would suggest you do in your query command, something like

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Col_Name,'dd-mm-yyyy') from Table_name where CONDITION;
```